# Show shortened reputation in rounded down form

Tags: feature-request, reputation, information-display

### Background

Where reputation is shown in shortened form it is rounded conventionally. That being;

- 0.5-0.99-->1
- 0.01-0.49-->0

So my current rep of 11,374 is shown as follows:

[image]

This doesn't really matter on desktop as the real rep is shown in the top bar, this isn't the case on mobile however.

### Feature request

Could shortened rep always be truncated (and probably other numbers too, for consistency), so I would be shown as having 11.3k.

### Reasoning

Ultimately I didn't care about moving from 9,949 to 9,951, but it looked like a big deal as it showed up as 10k, where I get "access to moderator tools", however when I actually got to 10k nothing changed. This tricked me at almost every rep level (possibly I shouldn't admit that).

Every single privilege sits at exactly divisible powers of 10 (apart from the very first ones) so it makes sense for the shown reputation be rounded such that when the shown reputation matches the required reputation you actually have the privilege.

Comment: I know, so frustrating, I just saw 20k but I don't have the privilege :-P

Comment: Won't this confuse non-programmers on the other SE sites who aren't expecting truncation?

Comment: I really don't see this as an issue; the problem is for a short time (the 49 points between 51 and 100), and is only confusing/misleading at three points in time as far as privileges go (10/15/20k), so it's a total of 147 rep points overall out of the first 20k. I didn't have any problem noticing when I actually hit those marks and got the privileges, personally. (Not downvoting, just mentioning. It's probably not worth the effort, or confusion it would create on other SE sites. It's kind of like the birthdays other than 16, 18, and 21; once you reach those, the others really don't count.)

Comment: @KenWhite Nitpick, but 19.5k rounds to 20k. Doorknob's SO rep is an example(as of now). So it's 500 there, not 50.

Comment: @Geobits: Yep, you're right. So the window where you're vulnerable to this is in fact a little larger (499 * 2 + 49), or a total of 1047 reputation points over a total of 20k (5.2%), but the last two gaps are less significant; by the time you reach 14.5k you should have enough answers posted that 499 points doesn't take you that long to earn. In my case, I found it made me work a little harder to finally get there once my rep started displaying that I had already. :-) Once you've reached 20k, there aren't any further privileges to earn via rep, so the rest are irrelevant.

Comment: @Geobits: A quick check of my own SO rep right now shows on an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21010399/62576) 62.9k, and my actual rep at this moment is 62,934. My point is that it won't matter a bit either way if I get another pair of answer upvotes and my displayed rep changes to 63k even though I actually only have 92,954.

Comment: @KenWhite Well I *did* preface that with "nitpick" ;)  I do agree with truncating them as a general principle. I don't think it matters *that* much one way or the other, but the coder in me feels better that way. Troyen does have a good point about the non-programmer sites, though.

Comment: @Geobits, I know. I wanted to show I really was capable of doing the math. I swear I did it in my head; the voices sometimes make it a little hard to pick out the right digits, though. ;-)

Comment: Just found this question, and I totally agree: it's confusing, regarding the privilege. As of current, my SO rep is 1500+, but it's shown as 2k, make me believe that I have privilege to edit directly :/

Answer (score 7):

I definitely agree with this. Having recently hit 100k on SO, for a short time prior I had to put up with the painful anti-climax of *looking* like I had 100k when in fact it was 99,980 or whatever.

I suppose there's no real justification for caring all that much, but it *does* seem like it would make more sense.