# Is it intentional that the profile reputation display in the revision history doesn't match the way it is displayed elsewhere?

Tags: support, reputation, revisions-list, information-display, user-card

I noticed that in the revision history, reputation over 10K isn't displayed in the shortened format used in other places. For example, in [the revision history for this question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/184970/revisions) my reputation on ELL is displayed as "11251" but it is displayed as "11.3K" when looking at the question. Is that intentional, or an oversight? I don't know if it has always been that way and I just noticed it, or if this is something new.

I prefer the shortened format, especially for users that have 100K or more reputation.

Comment: The closest existing question I could find was https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/show-shortened-reputation-in-rounded-down-form and that is about how the reputation is rounded, not that it isn't being shortened.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks! Searching on "flair" never occurred to me. I probably should have searched on the tags I picked instead of picking them after I searched.

Comment: Technically, “flair” refers to [these images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/273494/colleenv/flair); this, however, is the “user card”.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Do you think it is worth updating the duplicate to keep the language consistent?

Comment: Yes! I was hoping the bug would’ve been fixed by now, but now we might as well edit to correct the terminology…